# HTML search box to pick up values in a table

Tags: php, html, mysql

Okay this is abit hard to explain but I currently have a website where I'm using PHP and MySQL to pull tables into the web pages and display them. I've been able to make a search function to look for specific values in the table. I'll show you my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE php>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.php" media="screen">
</head>
<body>
<a id="TableButton" href="/Test.php">Items Table</a>
<a id="Clear" href="index.php">Clear Search</a>
<center>
<form method="GET" id="SearchPerson">
    <select name="Drop" id="Select">
      <option value="FirstName">First Name</option>
      <option value="Surname">Surname</option>
      <option value="MobileNumber">Mobile Number</option>
      <option value="Code">Code</option>    
      <option value="TeamGroup">Team Group</option>
      <option value="Home">Home</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="Box">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
</center>
<?php
 $host = "localhost";
 $user = "root";
 $pass = "password";
 $db = "Database";
 $connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ("Unable to connect!");
 mysql_select_db($db) or die ("Unable to select database!");
 if($_REQUEST['Drop']=='MobileNumber') {
    $MobileNumber = $_REQUEST['Box'];
    $query = "SELECT * From Person WHERE MobileNumber = $MobileNumber";
    }
 elseif($_REQUEST['Drop']=='Code') {
    $Code = $_REQUEST['Box'];
    $query = "SELECT * From Person WHERE Code = '$Code'";
    }
 elseif($_REQUEST['Drop']=='TeamGroup') {
    $TeamGroup = $_REQUEST['Box'];
    $query = "SELECT * From Person WHERE TeamGroup = '$TeamGroup'";
    }
 elseif($_GET['Drop']=='FirstName') {
    $FirstName = $_REQUEST['Box'];
    $query = "SELECT * From Person WHERE FirstName = '$FirstName'";
    }
 elseif($_GET['Drop']=='Surname') {
    $Surname = $_REQUEST['Box'];
    $query = "SELECT * From Person WHERE Surname = '$Surname'";
    }
 elseif($_REQUEST['Drop']=='Home') {
    $Home = $_REQUEST['Box'];
    $query = "SELECT * From Person WHERE Home = '$Home'";
    }
 else{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Person";
    }
 print "<center id=Title>Person Table</center>";
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query. ".mysql_error());
 if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    print '<center><table><tr>';
 foreach($row as $name => $value) {
    print "<th>$name</th>";
 }
 print '</tr>';
 while($row) {
 print '<tr>';
 foreach($row as $key=>$value) {
    if($key=='MobileNumber'){print "<td><a href='/Test.php?MobileNumber=$value'>$value</a></td>";}
    elseif($key=='TeamGroup'){print "<td><a href='/Test.php?TeamGroup=$value'>$value</a></td>";}
    elseif($key=='Group'){print "<td><a href='/Test.php?Home=$value'>$value</a></td>";}
    else{print "<td>$value</td>";}
 }
    print '</tr>';
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
 }
    print '</table></center>';    
 }  
 else {
 echo "No People found!";
 }

 mysql_free_result($result);

 mysql_close($connection);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Problem is even though I've got the search working it only works if I have the full values whereas i want it so say that i put part of someone mobile number in then itll display the mobile numbers that have those parts of the value in it. For example say that a few people had a mobile number starting with 0783 and I type that into the search box I want it to show up all people with 0783 in their mobile number.

Comment: Use `LIKE` http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-like/ and sidenote: `WHERE Group = '$Group'";` - `group` is a [**MySQL reserved word**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). Wrap it in backticks `\`` or rename it to something else. That alone should have triggered an error.

Comment: Ah thank you, i've changed it plus im looking into LIKE at the moment

Comment: You're welcome. There's also `SOUNDS LIKE` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#operator_sounds-like that may also be of interest.

Comment: Be careful when you are taking input directly from users and appending it to your queries.  Never trust the user.  Your queries are vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.  You should at least sanitize the input by using AddSlashes() for example. http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

Comment: I was going worry about the security after I've got it all up and running to a standard thats what I need, but thank you for linking me this.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `"SELECT * FROM Person WHERE MobileNumber LIKE '%".$_POST['MobileNumber']."%'"`, which will look for any string that contains the string you want, but may also be longer on either side. For example, `"foo"` will return the rows with values `"foobar"`, `"barfoo"`, `"barfoobar"` and of course `"foo"`, but not `"fo"`.

The `%` is a wildcard here, which means that you can also do something like `"SELECT * FROM Person WHERE MobileNumber LIKE '".$_POST['MobileNumber']."%'"` if you specifically want to return rows with values *starting* with your string (`"foobar"`, but not `"barfoo"` in our example above).

Please also note the `"` and `'`.

Also:

1. Don't use mysql_query. It's depreciated and will be removed in future versions of PHP. Use PDO or mysqli instead.
2. Your code is definitely not safe. At least use prepared statements to prevent injection. I would advise against using addslashes as it is very prone to resulting in double escapes if you are not paying attention, and as far as you may also want to go the magic_quotes, be aware it is not portable and may cause you trouble if you rely solely on this. Use `mysql_real_escape_string` instead, as it is very mysql-oriented and specific.

Comment: Thank You, For now where im working just in LocalHost im safe aren't I? At the moment this is just a prototype, if it does go up on the web I will consider alot of different security to make it safe.

Comment: You are "safe" as long as you don't enter stupid data, but your users will. It won't kill your machine if that's what you mean, but it wouldn't be too hard to seriously damage your database from here. And by "not too hard" I mean "very, very, very, very easy".
You will spend more time trying to find holes in your code (that is both wrong AND obsolete AND not guaranteed to work in the very near future) than to write it right in the first place, so consider taking a few hours to read about PDO (or Mysqli) and prepared statements, for example.

Comment: I'm Confused, If I've set character limits on each column of each table wont that stop someone from entering stupid amounts?
Can you give me an example?

Comment: try this for example: [first link on google for "drop database SQL injection"](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html)